# how to print lines using regur expression in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to print only the paricular strings from all lines in the file using re.search. i want to print only from `is` to `script`

For example file.txt contains:

> ```
> python is a nice script language
> dogs are smaller than tiger
> perl is a good script language
> ```

My code:

```
fo=open("file.txt","r")
for line in readlines():
    line=re.search(r"(is)(.*)(script",line)
    print line.group()
```

I am getting the error:

> none type object has no attribute group error

My output should be `is a nice script` on one line and `is a good script` on the next line.

Comment: are you using python-2.7 or python-3? Didn't get that

Comment: @almanegra it's just poorly tagged. Python version doesn't matter for this application

Comment: @AdamSmith rhetorical question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\bis (.*) script\b")
with open("file.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(pat.search(line).group(1))
```

Output is:

```
a nice script language dogs are smaller than tiger perl is a good
```

EDIT as per your new clarification in your question:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\bis a \w+ script\b")
# possibly re.compile(r"\bis(.*?)script\b")
with open('file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for match in pat.findall(line):
            print(match)
```

Output is:

```
is a nice script
is a good script
```

Comment: IMHO You shouldn't make his homework for him, but give leads to why it fails. Anyway, good answer, +1

Comment: @toasted_flakes you're probably right. Generally I take that approach as well on answers that appear to be homework problems. I admittedly did not give this my full attention.